# Order by query doesn't affect the result on THE PADS Hackerrank challenge

Tags: mysql, sql

right now im still practice sql. and try to solve challenge on hackkerank but i got some question and problem

> Here challenge that i take:
>
> "THE PADS"
>
> link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem?isFullScreen=true
>
> This challenge contains counting the number of people based on their job title and the goal is sort the number from smallest to greatest and after that, sort the occupation alfabeticaly.

---

#### Problem :

I tried to solve this by using `ORDER BY` but it doesn't seem to affect sorting number on the ouput

QUERY:

```
(Select concat(name,'(',LEFT(Occupation,1),')') as name from occupations) union 
(select concat('There are a total of ', count(*),' ', lower(occupation), 's.') 
from occupations group by occupation order by count(*) asc, occupation asc)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Ashley(P)
Samantha(A)
Julia(D)
Britney(P)
Maria(P)
Meera(P)
Priya(D)
Priyanka(P)
Jennifer(A)
Ketty(A)
Belvet(P)
Naomi(P)
Jane(S)
Jenny(S)
Kristeen(S)
Christeen(S)
Eve(A)
Aamina(D)
There are a total of 7 professors.
There are a total of 4 actors.
There are a total of 3 doctors.
There are a total of 4 singers.
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
Aamina(D)
Ashley(P)
Belvet(P)
Britney(P)
Christeen(S)
Eve(A)
Jane(S)
Jennifer(A)
Jenny(S)
Julia(D)
Ketty(A)
Kristeen(S)
Maria(P)
Meera(P)
Naomi(P)
Priya(D)
Priyanka(P)
Samantha(A)
There are a total of 3 doctors.
There are a total of 4 actors.
There are a total of 4 singers.
There are a total of 7 professors.
```

---

#### Question:

1. why my query doesn't work on hackkerank? i tried similiar method on w3school playground seem work normaly.

> Link playground w3school : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_concat

the query that i try on w3school:

```
SELECT concat(count(*), ' ',country)
from customers
group by country
ORDER BY count(*) asc
```

2. i try using someone solution, and its work but i dont understand why

```
(Select concat(name,'(',LEFT(Occupation,1),')') as name from occupations ) union 
( select concat("There are a total of ", count(Occupation)," ",lower(Occupation),"s.") 
from Occupations group by Occupation order by count(Occupation) ) ORDER BY name
```

- when i delete `order by count(Occupation)` the query still working, why?
- why using `ORDER BY name` instead of using `order by count(*)?

i will apreciate to any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Union of 2 sets ordered as required

```
select case rowtype 
   when 1 then concat(name,'(',LEFT(Occupation,1),')' )
   else concat ('There are a total of ',cnt,' ', lower(occupation), 's.')  end name
from  (
     select 1 rowtype, name, 0 cnt, Occupation 
     from occupations

     union 
     (
     select 2, null, count(*), Occupation           
     from occupations 
     group by occupation
     ) 
) t
order by rowtype, name, cnt, occupation
```

Comment: bit complex to me, what is cnt? is this mean abbreviation of count function? or just variable ?

Comment: `cnt` is an alias of a computed column.

Comment: whoa new things to learn,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

| 1 | Samantha | Doctor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Julia | Actor |
| 3 | Maria | Actor |
| 4 | Meera | Singer |
| 5 | Ashely | Professor |
| 6 | Keety | Professor |
| 7 | Christeen | Professor |
| 8 | Jane | Actor |
| 9 | Jenny | Doctor |
| 10 | Priya | Singer |
| 11 | Liam | Sportman |

Let's split the queries:

```
SELECT Name || "(" || SUBSTRING(Occupation, 1, 1) || ")" AS Jobs
FROM occupations_table
ORDER BY Name
```

| Jobs |
| --- |
| Ashely(P) |
| Christeen(P) |
| Jane(A) |
| Jenny(D) |
| Julia(A) |
| Keety(P) |
| Liam(S) |
| Maria(A) |
| Meera(S) |
| Priya(S) |
| Samantha(D) |

```
SELECT "There are a total of " || COUNT(*) || " " || Occupation AS Report
FROM occupations_table
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(*), Occupation
```

| Report |
| --- |
| There are a total of 1 Sportman |
| There are a total of 2 Doctor |
| There are a total of 2 Singer |
| There are a total of 3 Actor |
| There are a total of 3 Professor |

You can't `UNION` them with the group by or the whole query will fail, but you can `ORDER BY` after `UNION` and you should get the expected result, or at least i'm getting it by running the following code on a sqlite build

```
SELECT Name || "(" || SUBSTRING(Occupation, 1, 1) || ")" AS Jobs
FROM occupations
UNION
SELECT "There are a total of " || COUNT(*) || " " || Occupation AS Quantity
FROM occupations
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY Jobs, Quantity
```

| Jobs |
| --- |
| Ashely(P) |
| Christeen(P) |
| Jane(A) |
| Jenny(D) |
| Julia(A) |
| Keety(P) |
| Liam(S) |
| Maria(A) |
| Meera(S) |
| Priya(S) |
| Samantha(D) |
| There are a total of 1 Sportman |
| There are a total of 2 Doctor |
| There are a total of 2 Singer |
| There are a total of 3 Actor |
| There are a total of 3 Professor |

Comment: This looks like an oracle answer to a mysql question (|| is OR in mysql) and may confuse the OP

Comment: the query that you write seem error in mysql, but i re-write using concat(). but it gets error when i run query. error msg : "ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'Quantity' in 'order clause'".

Comment: and i try remove "Quantity" in ORDER BY, so will be "ORDER BY Jobs" and it work. i think it coincedence expected output. so i try re-write to be "ORDER BY Jobs" with "ORDER BY Occupation" or "ORDER BY Quantity", it gets error msg on above this comment. can you explain why i can use "ORDER BY occupation" / "ORDER BY occupation"

Comment: here the re-write code : SELECT concat(name,'(',LEFT(Occupation,1),')') as Jobs from occupations
UNION
SELECT concat('There are a total of ', count(*),' ', lower(occupation), 's.') AS Quantity
FROM occupations
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY Jobs

Comment: Ja i just wanted to share the concept, but i wrtote it on sqlite to give it a try. You can move the platform specific keywords from sqlite syntax to mmysql syntax, sorry for leaving back that part.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work:
SELECT Name + '('+ substring(Occupation, 1, 1) +')'
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY Name ;
SELECT 'There are a total of  ' + str(count(Occupation)) + ' '+ substring(LOWER(Occupation), 1, 1) + substring(Occupation, 2, LEN(Occupation)-1) + 's.'
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY count(Occupation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).